# Matlab plot second x axis position

Tags: matlab, plot

I tried to add second x axis, it can be just the copy of first one, same data.
But when i add the axis it doesnt only change the y-Position, as specfied, it also changes x and the axis itself is cut, not visible

```
f = 10;
N=[3,5,8,13];

eff_t(1) = 12.4758 - j *6.5914;
eff_f(1) = 12.4615;

n_t(1) = 0.0298;
n_est(1) = 0.0321;

eff_f(2) = 12.3662 - j *7.473;
eff_t(2) = 12.3532 - j *6.5202;

n_t(2) = 0.0496;
n_est(2) = 0.0475;

eff_f(3) = 12.0535 - j *6.327;
eff_t(3) = 12.1708 - j *6.4143;

n_t(3) = 0.0794;
n_est(3) = 0.0987;

eff_f(4) = 12.0328 - j *6.4102;
eff_t(4) = 11.8707 - j *6.2402;

n_t(4) = 0.12;
n_est(4) = 0.10;

figure(1)
yyaxis left
plot(N, eff_f,'b-o', N, eff_t, 'r-o','Linewidth',2);
ylabel('Realteil der rel. Permittivität \epsilonS und \epsilonMG');
yyaxis right
plot(N, n_est, 'k--o',N, n_t,'g--o','Linewidth',2);
ylabel('Porosität nS und nMG');

legend('\epsilonS','\epsilonMG','nS','nMG');

grid on
%grid minor
set(gca,'FontSize', 20);
set(gca,'Linewidth',1.8);

 xlabel('N Anzahl der Poren');

 title('Permittivität und Porosität für f = 10 GHz');

 a1Pos = get(gca,'Position');

%// Place axis 2 below the 1st.
ax2 = axes('Position',[a1Pos(1) (a1Pos(2)-0.3) a1Pos(3) a1Pos(4)],'Color','none','YTick',[],'YTickLabel',[]);
```

[image]

Comment: Show a picture of what you get and what's desired if possible.

Comment: Probably you have read [this](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/graph-with-multiple-x-axes-and-y-axes.html?s_tid=gn_loc_drop). But why not `ax1.Position` instead of explicit positioning.

Comment: edited the foto

Comment: I have never seen something like this. Why you don't place the 2nd x-axis on top?